# Keyword not supported :Column Encryption Setting=enabled

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-2.0

I am having an issue with missing column encryption in ASP.NET web.config file.

I add: `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` but I get an error:

> Keyword not supported

My Code:

```cs
string connectionString = "Data Source=server63; Initial Catalog=Clinic; IntegratedSecurity=true; Column Encryption Setting=enabled";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I am using .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: [Added in 4.6](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.ColumnEncryptionSetting). Time to upgrade.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Or are you using something along the lines of: ColumnEncryptionSetting = SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting.Enabled;

Comment: @shox: `ColumnEncryptionSetting` and `SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting` were also added in 4.6, so there's no way it would compile with .NET Framework 2.0 if OP were using those in the code. It's giving that message because it's a connection string and it doesn't get parsed and rejected until run time when it's passed to `SqlConnection`'s constructor (as in this case) or assigned to the `ConnectionString` property.

Comment: @madreflection thanks, I could barely understand what they were trying to describe, I was just reviewing as a first question. You are quite right on all your points. Whether it's worth clarifying the question and adding your comment as an answer.. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @madreflection thanks for your reply. Is that any solution without changing framework versions?